# SQL GROUP_CONCAT returns unwanted NULLs

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a problem in my SQL query which i'm unable to solve so far...

```
SELECT `m` . * , `s`.`id` AS `user_id` ,
    CONCAT( s.firstname, s.lastname ) AS `name` ,
    `s`.`email` , `mu`.`status` , `r`.`id` AS `user_id` ,
    GROUP_CONCAT( r.firstname, r.lastname
SEPARATOR "," ) AS `name` , `r`.`email`
FROM `messages` AS `m`
INNER JOIN `users` AS `s` ON m.from = s.id
INNER JOIN `messages_users` AS `mu` ON m.id = mu.message_id
INNER JOIN `users` AS `r` ON r.id = mu.user_id
WHERE (
m.id = '183'
)
```

The problem is in the GROUP_CONCAT I think. It works as it should when indeed matches are found. But when nothing is found, all fields return NULL. In stead of NULL I want it to return no rows.
The query works when using CONCAT, but I really need all the names combined in one row, not multiple rows.

Comment: Maybe add a `HAVING COUNT(*) > 0` clause after `WHERE`.

Comment: `GROUP_CONCAT()` is an aggregate but you have no `GROUP BY`. Does your query otherwise return only _one row_?

Comment: Indeed it returns one value, multiple names (recipients) are grouped into one name field

Comment: `HAVING COUNT(*) > 0` solved the problem @biziclop

Comment: Maybe you could also add an explicit `GROUP BY m.id` just to be clean :)